# How can i get redirect same page without refresh?

Tags: visualforce, redirect

I have created visual force pages in added in related object page layout. Once I select the record and save it not redirect the page. Why this happening? How can I resolve this issue. Please can any one help me out. Please find the below images.

[image]

Comment: We won't be able to help you without seeing the code for your Visualforce page and (if relevant) your Apex controller.